# Parse Javascript - Query on array of ParseObjects

Tags: parse-platform

I have the following structure

- `User`: have a field called `systems_ref` that is an Array of Systems
- `Systems`: have a field called `monitors` that is an array of Monitors
- `Monitors`: is a collection

First of all i get all Systems from the User, with include:

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User.current());
userQuery.include("systems_ref");
```

Now that i have an array of Systems i would like to do the same as before, query Systems (including `monitors`).

So, i have an array of Systems and i want to query all of them and for each one, get the `systems_ref`

The query on Systems will be

```
var Systems = Parse.Object.extend("systems");
var systemQuery = new Parse.Query(Systems);
systemQuery.include("monitors");
```

But, what constraint i have to add to `systemQuery` to query a Array of ParseObject ?